# How Do I Start a New Row In a Fixed Position Flexbox?

Tags: html, css

This is my css:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.96);
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
}

.buttonBar {
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  color: red;
}

.theImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

.button {
  float: left;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<div class="button">
    <button id="open">Test</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop">
    <img class="theImage" src=index.png />
    <div class="buttonBar">button bar</div>
</div>

<!-- page 108 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById('open');
    var drawer = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0];
    var height = drawer.scrollHeight;
    var width = drawer.scrollWidth;
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    drawer.style.setProperty('width', '350px');
    drawer.style.setProperty('height', height + 'px');
});
</script>
```

The button bar doesn't have any buttons in it yet and the text is just a placeholder. I want that button bar to go under the img tag but all it does is overlap the img. Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add position absolute or fixed to `.theImage` or `.buttonBar`.

Just use `flex-direction: column;` and buttonBar div will be under image.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aof6ysmn/

Comment: God bless you, sir.